# Material UI's CSSBaseline breaking react-mentions

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to figure out why CSSBaseline of Material UI is breaking the background color alignment of React-mentions and how to solve this (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mentions)

Take a look at the following setup:
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wildflower-21wqm

Currently I'm pretty much stuck and I really hope someone can help me to find the fix.

Please let me know if there are any questions.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is the `line-height` property set by the MuiBaseline; To solve, simply reset it to `1`, as:

```css
* {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Working solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-glitter-4j0c5?file=/src/styles.css